# Regex only match one time

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regex pattern to match all words that exactly have one **e** and one **i**. The order does not matter!

I tried it with `{,1}` , still matches two and more.
Tried it with ? here the same , still more matches.

Example words:

```
bier = true
biier = false
beir = true 
qwertyie = false
```

Patterns I've tried:

```
grep -E "^i?{1,1}"

grep -E "^i{1,1}"

grep -E "^i{1,1}$"

grep -E "^.*i?{1,1}.*$"
```

Comment: show the regex please

Comment: *I tried it with {,1}* where's that try?

Comment: @anubhava the last word has 2 e, beir only one e and one i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{,1}` is not a valid regex.

You are trying to parse something that has two conditions: one `e`, and one `i`; or else one `i`, and one `e`.

I'd try something like:

```
egrep "^([^ei]*e[^ei]*i[^ei]*|[^ei]*i[^ei]*e[^ei]*)$" file
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me would be to split the requirement. I'll grep for the first requirement first, then pass the result to a second `grep`:

```
grep "^[^ei]*e[^ei]*$" <file>|grep "^[^ei]*i[^ei]*$"
```

Comment: You will end up with just nothing :-)

Comment: I saw this somewhere , that the regex was devided into two. Is there really no way to make in one call ?

Comment: @cadrian is correct, I wasn't thinking very well. His solution works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk as an alternative to a complex regex:

```
awk 'split($0,a,"i")<=2 && split($0,b,"e")<=2{print "true"; exit} {print "false"}' <<< "$s"
```

**Examples:**

```
awk 'split($0,a,"i")<=2 && split($0,b,"e")<=2{print "true"; exit} {print "false"}'<<<'bier'
true
awk 'split($0,a,"i")<=2 && split($0,b,"e")<=2{print "true"; exit} {print "false"}'<<<'biier'
false
awk 'split($0,a,"i")<=2 && split($0,b,"e")<=2{print "true"; exit} {print "false"}'<<<'beir'
true
awk 'split($0,a,"i")<=2 && split($0,b,"e")<=2{print "true"; exit} {print "false"}'<<<'qwertyie'
false
```